# Set CirclePageIndicator on Viewpager in android

Tags: android

I have 4 page on view pager. I want only show 3 CirclePageIndicator at page 1, page 2, page 3. Page 4 not show CirclePageIndicator.

```
 mString1 = new int[]{R.string.text_guide_1, R.string.text_guide_2, R.string.text_guide_3, R.string.text_guide_10};
    mString2 = new int[]{R.string.text_guide_4, R.string.text_guide_5, R.string.text_guide_6, R.string.text_guide_11};
    mString3 = new int[]{R.string.text_guide_7, R.string.text_guide_8, R.string.text_guide_9, R.string.text_guide_12};
    GuideAdapter adapter = new GuideAdapter(this, getContext(), mString1, mString2, mString3, this);
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
    mCirclePageIndicator.setRadius(18);
    mCirclePageIndicator.setPageColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    mCirclePageIndicator.setFillColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    mCirclePageIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mCirclePageIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
```

My code. It show all CirclePageIndicator on Viewpager. Please. Help me!

File Adapter

```
public class GuideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int[] mListString1;
private int[] mListString2;
private int[] mListString3;
private Context mContext;
private CustomDialog customDialog;

public GuideAdapter(CustomDialog customDialog, Context mContext, int[] mString1, int[] mString2, int[] mString3,PageClickListener callback) {
    this.customDialog = customDialog;
    this.mListString1 = mString1;
    this.mListString2 = mString2;
    this.mListString3 = mString3;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mCallback = callback;

}

public interface PageClickListener {
    void onPageClick(int id);
}

private PageClickListener mCallback;


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListString1.length;
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View imageLayout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_guide, container, false);
    assert imageLayout != null;
    TextView text_1 = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    TextView text_2 = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
    TextView text_3 = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
    text_1.setText(mListString1[position]);
    text_2.setText(mListString2[position]);
    text_3.setText(mListString3[position]);
    text_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCallback.onPageClick(position);
        }
    });
    text_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCallback.onPageClick(position);
        }
    });
    text_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCallback.onPageClick(position);
        }
    });

    container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
    return imageLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}
```

Please. Help me!

Comment: you are sending onlu 3 items to adapter I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override **setOnPageChangeListener** and in your last page hide your circleIndicator.

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {

        if(position > 2) {
             //hide indicator

        } else if(position < 2) {
             //visible indicator
        }

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: I scroll viewpager to position 2. circleIndicator hide. But I want. When open view pager. Position 2 not show circleIndicator. Please. Help me!

Comment: @JackyChan change position by your need , It's just an example. in your case set it to 3

Comment: Yes. I know. It's just an example. you can misinterpret my comments.
My code, it show 4  circleIndicator on view pager. I want when I open app. It only show 3  circleIndicator. Please. Help me

Comment: why you need this ? when you attach indicator to your ViewPager it's return number of your pages. I think you should handle it in another way

Comment: override  CirclePageIndicator ( you can find source code here https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/library ) and modify number of page which return.

Comment: thank. I change count = getCount() - 1;. It worked!
  @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mViewPager == null) {
            return;
        }
        final int count = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding onPageListener. Just make your class implements ONpagechangelistener and then take one field for updating the currenpage position and then on each update check if updated position is equal to array length or not if it is just ignore the circularpageindicator.

Comment: I want when I open view pager. circleIndicator not show at last position. circleIndicator only show at page 1, page 2, page 3. Please. help me!